# Auto try catch router controller with async await

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Router:

```
  router.get('/available', VehicleController.getAvailable)

  router.put('/:vin/current-location', validate(vehicleValidation.currentLocation), VehicleController.saveCurrentLocation)
```

Controller

```
class VehicleController {
  async getAvailable (req, res, next) {
    try {
      res.json(await VehicleQueries.getAvailable())
    } catch (e) {
      next(e)
    }
  }

  async saveCurrentLocation (req, res, next) {
    try {
      res.json(await VehicleQueries.updateLocation(req.params.vin, req.body.lng, req.body.lat))
    } catch (e) {
      next(e)
    }
  }... etc etc
```

The above is a simple crud app built in nodejs using the new async and await. Each route validates the input then passes onto the controller. The examples above call methods in another class containing the queries which in turn return a promise.

As you can see I have to wrap the code of each controller in a try and catch.. this is getting fairly irritating and i think there must be a cleaner way.

Is it possible to somehow wrap the controller method itself in a try catch? This way i could simplify the controllers to:

```
class VehicleController {
  async getAvailable (req, res, next) {
      res.json(await VehicleQueries.getAvailable())
  }

  async saveCurrentLocation (req, res, next) {
      res.json(await VehicleQueries.updateLocation(req.params.vin, req.body.lng, req.body.lat))
  }... etc etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage [rest paremeters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to build a function to handle the try/catch

```
async executeQuery(res,next,queryFunction,...queryArguments){
    try {
        res.json(await queryFunction(...queryArguments));
    } catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
}
async getAvailable (req, res, next) {
    executeQuery(res,next,VehicleQueries.getAvailable);
}

async saveCurrentLocation (req, res, next) {
    executeQuery(res,next,VehicleQueries.updateLocation,req.params.vin, req.body.lng, req.body.lat);
}
```

Comment: yes but to me this feels like i am passing the output command deeper into the app and is would now be quite specific to the queries class. Would be great if there was a middleware somehow that could handle the catch. Something at the router level somehow, that the router tries the controller then on a catch calls next. Instead of passing the responsibility to the controller, but i cannot think how to do it.

Comment: It looks like they have guides on [error handling middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) I tried to make a mini app to test it out with no luck. You could give it a go and see if it works for you

Comment: Yes I had the same issue, but it feels like the data flow is router -> action -> errorHandler. Where as the solution i am aiming for is router -> try action -> catchErrorHandler. If I find the answer i will post on back. Thanks for your help.